# Predict Google Play ratings with Weka

Tags: machine-learning, google-play, weka, metrics, prediction

I am newbie in Weka 3.7.9.
I have got an arff file, which contains these attributes, class and data:
http://pastebin.com/s8hivv0U

This file representing Android projects.
So, the 1-9. attributes are different kinds of metrics:

1. lloc - Logical Lines Of Code
2. nid - Number Of IDs
3. nle - Nesting Level
4. nel - Number of Elements
5. nip - Number of Input elements
6. activites - number of activities from AndroidManifest
7. inside-permissions - number of inside permissions from AndroidManifest
8. outside-permissions - number of outside permissions from AndroidManifest
9. all-permissions - number of permissions from AndroidManifest
10. class {4, 4.6, 3.8, 2.6. 5, 3.2, 3.6, 4.2, 4.1}

The last is a class which contains the Google Play rating of projects.

So each lines are Andorid projects. (Naturally, the original *.arff file contains more projects...)

I would like to analyze datas with learning algorithms.
The predictors are from 1 to 9.
I would like to determine, what predictors influence mostly the Google Play ratings.

How can i do that?
And what is the best methods to do it?
I would like ask you to explain it to me, if it is possible.

Thanks in advance,
Peter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Class type

First, I would suggest that you make you change your `class` type to `numeric`, if you would like your output to be continuous. Otherwise, I'd suggest keeping the class label type as `nominal` (as you have it now) but change your ratings to `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`.

If you change to a numeric output (so you can give a prediction of 4.5 stars, for example), then you'll need to use a classifier that is capable of a numeric class.

### Using Weka

I'd suggest taking a look at the [documentation](http://www.cs.waikato.ac.nz/ml/weka/documentation.html) to learn more about using Weka, possibly by going through some tutorials. For example, after double-clicking your ARFF-file, you should be doing most of your work in the `Classify` tab. Select a classifier, then choose `Start`.

### Classifiers

#### Regression

[Regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) and in particular [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) is nice because it is easy to interpret because it simply assigns a weight to each of your attributes and uses multiplication and addition of those weights to give an output.

I used your example file and tested it with `LinearRegression`, however with such few samples it determined that the best model was simply to output `3.9667` as the rating and that will give you a mean absolute error of `0.4722`.

Not satisfied, next I tried `SimpleLinearRegression`, which gives a model  `-0.02 * activites + 4.13`, and will give a mean absolute error of `0.472`.

`SMOreg` gives the following model

```
weights:
 +       0.1147 * (normalized) lloc
 -       0.0404 * (normalized) nid
 -       0.1662 * (normalized) nle
 -       0.0647 * (normalized) nel
 +       0.3385 * (normalized) nip
 -       0.1352 * (normalized) activites
 -       0.019  * (normalized) inside-permissions
 -       0.0464 * (normalized) outside-permissions
 +       0.1602 * (normalized) all-permissions
 +       0.5921
```

and has a mean absolute error of `0.3859`. But at this point, I think with such few data points you are [overfitting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Overfitting) your data.

#### Nearest neighbor

Using [k-nearest neighbors](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm) might be a viable approach, if you have more data (in Weka it is called `KStar`).

#### Decision trees

The `DecisionStump` algorithm outputs this model with a mean absolute error of `0.3424`, but again probably overfitting.

```
inside-permissions <= 1.5 : 2.6
inside-permissions > 1.5 : 4.090909090909091
inside-permissions is missing : 3.966666666666667
```

### More data

As you can see, the models and error rates are not so great, considering you only have 12 data points. To build a really good model, you'll need more data. To get an accurate idea of how well the model is doing, you need to not only have enough data to train with, but enough data to keep as a separate test set that you only use for testing the performance of your model.

Comment: Hi!Thanks your amazing and very useful help :)
I will check what you answered me, i will give feedback sooner or later.
Thanks.

Comment: I would like to know, why can i change ratings?
So now i have these ratings:
@attribute class {4, 4.6, 3.8, 2.6, 5, 3.2, 3.6, 4.2, 4.1}

If i change this line, i have to change each "@data" end of line in this file.
I think i lose accuracy if i use only {1,2,3,4,5} ratings.
Why it is a good solution?

Comment: @olhptr You lose precision (but probably gain accuracy). If I was using discrete class labels, I would explicitly use `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`(or maybe `{1, 1.5, 2, 2.5, ...}`). Otherwise you have to add another label each time you get a new unique rating (`4.6` or `3.8`). Plus, the classifier doesn't know that `2.6` is different than `B` or `Positive`. However, if you switch to `numeric` type, then the classifier knows the output is simply a (continuous range) number. Hope that helps.

Comment: So, if i not misunderstood what you sad, that it is a good construction for analyze:
http://pastebin.com/eaKqHhfV

or not?

Comment: @olhptr Yes, setting `google-play-rating numeric` will allow the classifier to output a number. However, since you are using `numeric` you **can keep** the original ratings for each data point (like `3.6`, etc.).

Comment: I used linear regression on this set: http://pastebin.com/gRUGR6ug .
The result is: http://pastebin.com/hzCcN44b . You can see: `google-play-rating =
 
      0.0004 * lloc +
      0.0048 * nip +
     -0.0657 * activites +
      4.2071`. I don't understand why only `lloc`, `nip`, `activities` in the model. Where are the other attributes and why they aren't in this linear regression model?
I think i would use more data because the mean absolute error is `0.2996` . Or how can i reduced the value of it?

Comment: @olhptr For example: notice that the weight for `lloc` is nearly zero. This means that it has nearly no effect on the rating-calculation. The other attributes aren't there because their weight is so low (near zero) that they don't contribute to the model's estimation at all. This either means that you can predict the rating with only the attributes it gives, *or more likely* you need more training data.

Comment: Thanks your reply, sorry my dumb question.